# Minimal value of $\mathbb{E}[(X-g(Y))^2]$.

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, variance

In a test I have two true/false question and I'm not sure if I got it properly:

Given X and Y as two random variable (we don't know if indipendent), with $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$:

1. $g(Y)=\mathbb{E}[X|Y]$ makes $\mathbb{E}[(X-g(Y))^2]$ minimal
2. $c=var[X]$ makes $\mathbb{E}[(X-c)^2]$ minimal

Now, in both cases the second part resemble the formula of the variance, but I don't think I need it.

Due to the fact that both $\mathbb{E}[(X-g(Y))^2]$ and $\mathbb{E}[(X-c)^2]$ are the expected value of a square, the minimal value that they can get is zero, and they get it when $g(Y)=X$ and $c=X$.

So both the the answers should be false, but I'm not really sure if I'm missing something, can you confirm that my logic is right?

Comment: "minimal" : minimal *among which set of random variables*? $1$ is the smallest number in $\{1,2\}$ and $4$ is the smallest number in $\{4,5,7\}$ : both statements are correct, so the question is incomplete because it does not specify what the set is , over which you have to minimize that quantity. I mean, for example statement $2$ is wrong if $c$ was over all random variables, because then I could just take $c=X$. But $c$ varies over all real numbers, so then $2$ is correct. Something similar occurs in $1$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think the "semantic" problem is due to the fact that I'm not a native english speaker and I'm trying to translate it as best as possibile and math is pretty sensibile to "meaning" error. I agree too that the test is a little vague in the language, but I think it means "the lowest possible value in R", I'm sorry if my translation isn't perfect

Comment: Two things. One, if it means the lowest possible value in $\mathbb R$ then things are good. Second : someone else might get the language of the paper you are looking at, so can you attach a link  to the question with language intact?

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that when trying to define an estimator function such as $g(\cdot )$, we should note it to be **deterministic rather than stochastic**. The substitution $g(X)=X$ may sound reasonably good, but impractical due to it uselessness because we don't know the exact amount of $X$. Instead, we can exploit additional information, say $Y$, to make a best possible (from the aspect of minimum error variance) estimation of $X$. The more $Y$ is dependent to $X$, the better the estimator is .